# When Apple app association file downloaded to iOS device

Tags: ios, objective-c, deep-linking

We have deployed the app-association file to production server. Now I would like to add a new path to app-association file. So my question is whether new app-association file will get dowloaded to user device when new app is installed or app update?

OR will it get updated in user device immediately when app-association file is updated in server?

Appreciate your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `apple-app-site-association` file is pulled when the app is first downloaded, and whenever an update is downloaded from the App Store. So basically you'll need to release a new version of the app before all your existing users see the new path.

Comment: `Whenever an update is downloaded from the App Store` has this been confirmed? We're struggling with this right now.We would like to update the associations file (we're using it as a black list), but the device/installed app doesn't update the list - unless it's reinstalled. We've just tested it with an update, and that didn't seem to do the trick. Thanks

Comment: @micmdk yes, in my experience that is the case, though I can't absolutely prove it is true since Apple doesn't document this anywhere. You could try looking at the device logs directly...those might show more information.

Comment: So it turned out that we where upgrading a TestFlight build, with the same version from AppStore which then didn't trigger the association file update. When we updated an old AppStore app with a new one from AppStore it worked - thanks!

Comment: @micmdk, oh that is _fascinating_. An edge case I would never have guessed. Thanks for sharing!